# Laravel migrate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migrate

I have some problems with php artisan migrate. It's only install users and migrations in database but no other files that i have. I installed this project https://github.com/thedevdojo/chatter so you can be sure that code is clear and it's working, it's not problem only on this project but when i type php artisan make:auth it's not installing reset password table but only users and it says like this:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or
>   view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create
>   table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary
>   key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null,
>   `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null,
>   `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` tim   estamp null) default
>   character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists:
>   1050 Table 'users' already exists

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me- you are trying to create a table with the name `users`, but one already exists.

Comment: I type only php artisan migrate and it should install all databases that is not installed not only users. Just users installs not eaven password reset that is included to php artisan make:auth. But when i type php artisan migrate:status i can see all migrations, i don't know what is the problem

Comment: you are going to have to be more clear.

Comment: It **IS** installing a new table called `users`, but you already have one.  You need to either delete the existing table, or create a new database.

Comment: Okay i deleted table users and when i type again "php artisan migrate" it's only installs users but no other tables.

Comment: @Rade- I am guessing it is throwing a similar error- you need to delete ALL of your tables.

Comment: @DerekBrown fixed i find it on youtube it was Schema. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try to drop your table in database and do re-migration. if it still didn't work you can check your database.php in folder config. change every utf8mb4 to utf8. This is example before you change your database.php :

```js
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

And after you change:

```js
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

After that you can to drop manual all table in you db, and then do migration again.